# Twilio runtime function gives invalid Access token on iOS quickstart

Tags: swift, twilio, twilio-video

I am using twilio runtime function to generate access token successfully on browser. Below is the attached screenshot.

[image]

But when I run that url on iOS quickstart project, it gives me invalid access token error when I am connecting room. Kindly help. Below is the url I use in my project.

```
var tokenUrl = "https://ochre-piranha-2040.twil.io/video-token"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the identity is missing from your video token, you should have:

```
{
  "jti": "SKad6ba74ba95c959a69cec1f735c992c9-1581234567",
  "grants": {
    "identity": "JohnDoe",
    "video": {}
  },
  "iat": 1589364684,
  "exp": 1589368284,
  "iss": "SKad6ba74ba95c959a69cec1f731234567",
  "sub": "AC27740274e921b6c90991edde01234567"
}
```

[User Identity & Access Tokens](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/user-identity-access-tokens)